# Mocked method still being executed

Tags: android, mockito, powermock

I am running this test in an Android codebase. My target method relies on another method which checks for network connectivity. Since network connectivity check has an Android dependency, I tried to mock that method. Still, it's being executed and I am getting an NPE where Android context method is being used. I have tried both Roboelectric and Junit runners.

```
import android.content.Context;

import org.junit.Test;
import org.junit.runner.RunWith;
import org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito;
import org.powermock.core.classloader.annotations.PrepareForTest;
import org.robolectric.RobolectricTestRunner;
import org.robolectric.annotation.Config;

import static org.junit.Assert.*;
import static org.mockito.Matchers.any;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.mock;
import static org.powermock.api.mockito.PowerMockito.when;


@RunWith(RobolectricTestRunner.class)
@Config(manifest = Config.NONE)
@PrepareForTest({Network.class, Messages.class})
public class MessagesTest {

    @Test
    public void getStatus() throws Exception {
        PowerMockito.mockStatic(Network.class);
        when(Network.isConnected(any(Context.class))).thenReturn(false);
        String s = Messages.getStatus(mock(Context.class));
        assertEquals(s, "offline");
    }

}




public class Messages {

    public static String getStatus(Context context){
        if(Network.isConnected(context)) return "online";
        else return "offline";
    }
}



public class Network {

    private static final String MOBILE = "MOBILE";
    private static final String WIFI = "WIFI";


    public static boolean isConnected(Context context) {
        boolean isWifiConnected = false;
        boolean isMobileConnected = false;

        ConnectivityManager connectivityManager = (ConnectivityManager) context.getSystemService(Context.CONNECTIVITY_SERVICE);
        NetworkInfo[] allNetworkInfo = connectivityManager.getAllNetworkInfo();
        for (NetworkInfo networkInfo : allNetworkInfo) {
            if (networkInfo != null && WIFI.equalsIgnoreCase(networkInfo.getTypeName())) {
                isWifiConnected = networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }

            if (networkInfo != null && MOBILE.equalsIgnoreCase(networkInfo.getTypeName())) {
                isMobileConnected = networkInfo.isConnectedOrConnecting();
            }

        }
        return isWifiConnected || isMobileConnected;
    }
}
```

NPE is thrown in `Network` class where `context.getSystemService()` is being invoked.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like I just needed a `PowerMockRunner` instead of `RobolectricTestRunner`. If `RobolectricTestRunner` is used, then we should also add the following:

```
@Rule
public PowerMockRule powerMockRule = new PowerMockRule();

@Rule
public MockitoRule mockitoRule = MockitoJUnit.rule();
```